# Little CSS problem with Auto height and nested div's

Tags: css, height

So I'm finally learning my way around CSS more and have run into a small problem. I have a container div, with a few divs inside of it, one of them is a bit of text (which can be a random height) and an image that will have a MAX height of 200px.

I am using a dotted/colored background behind them that needs to auto expand to the height of whichever is the tallest, either the text or the image. Right now when I use `height:auto` on the container div it works perfect for the random height text.

But it's only adjusting according to the text's height; if the image is taller than the text, the image overflows the bottom of the background dotted/colored box.

The CSS I'm using currently is this:

```
h1 div#like_detailed {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 700px;
}

#details-image img {
  border: none;
  clear: left;
  float: right;
  margin: -45px 0 0 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 0 7px 0 10px;
}

#deets-container {
  background-color: #FEF;
  border: #190AE7 1px dotted;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

And the HTML for it is this:

```
<div id="deets-container" class="rounded">
<!-- Button -->
<div class="likebtnframe">(some code)</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="tweetbtnframe">(some code)</div>
<!-- Button -->
<ul id="share">
<li><a name="share">(some code)</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Submitted By -->
<div class="submitter_detailed"><span class="submitter-color smalltext">(some code)</span> (some code)</div>
<!-- Image -->
<div id="**details-image**">(some code)</div>
<!-- Like / Quote -->
<h1 id="**like_detailed**">(some code)</h1>
</div>
```

I have a feeling this is pretty easy but I'm running out of time to sort it out on my own.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you haven't cleared your div which contains your floated image. The best solution to this is to use [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {  content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden;    } 
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Anything that contains floated elements always needs to be cleared unless of course you set a fixed height for that element.

Now change your html from this:

```
<div id="deets-container" class="rounded">
```

to this:

```
<div id="deets-container" class="rounded clearfix">
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are floating the `img` element inside of `#details-image`.

When an element is floated, its containing element effectively ignores it, unless it is also floated. So what that means is when you float your image, the containing div no longer calculates it as part of its contents, and so does not include it in its height.

There is a trick to handle this that I like use:

```
div.anchor {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
}
```

Now add one of these anchor divs **immediately** after your `img` element, and include a non-breaking space inside of it (some browsers will not render it if it is totally empty).

```
<div id="details-image">
    (some code)
    <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" />
    <div class="anchor">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

This works because by adding a "`clear`" to the element, you are forcing it to be included with floated elements, but by setting `float:none`, you are making it's non-floating parent recognize it and include it as well. The clear property will make it clear the floated element and render after it, and since the `line-height` and `font-size` are `0` it won't add any extra height. I know it all sounds weird but give it a go, I use this method all the time in tableless layouts with a lot of floating divs.

For reference: here's a [great read](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) from A List Apart about CSS Floats

Answer (score 0):

float 'kills' the height calculation somehow: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
explains why  (I found that here on Stack) and explains hoe "clear" works